# What do you call a scammer who sell products through the phone?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure if there's a word for it, but I am almost positive that I heard a word for it. It might be a noun or it might be a verb, but there was definitely a word for it.

For example, let's take the following example:

> The ___ sold me some insurance product that didn't suit my need at
>   all, which led me to financial ruin.

The only word I can think of are telemarketer and scammer, but those two words are too general.

Comment: ...which **led** me to financial ruin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an actual sales person selling you a real product, then "telemarketer" is the correct word for this context.  If it's a fraudulent transaction, then "scammer" is the correct word.

You may be thinking of words for various types of scammers, such as: *cheater, chiseler, con man or confidence man, cozener, defrauder, dodger, fakir, finagler, fraudster, hoaxer, hustler, scamster, shark, sharper, sharpie (or sharpy), skinner, swindler, tricker, trickster* and probably a number of others.

Comment: Those telecozeners really are a nuisance.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  not to mention the *telesharks*.   Don't go near the handset.